# C# winform - Find file type based on data, not extensions

Tags: c#, winforms

So here's my problem - I've got a ton of files that all have the same file extension (e.g., .aabc) but are all widely different file types. Some could be emails, others could be videos. Point is, I don't know what these files are and I need to convert them to something usable but to do that, I need to find out what they are.

I've tried the [Mime-Detective nuget extension](https://github.com/MediatedCommunications/Mime-Detective) but that doesn't want to work. The "ContentInspectorBuilder" class doesn't have an inspect method like in the example code on the GitHub. Below is what I've done for it

```
using System;
using System.IO;
using System.Security;
using System.Windows.Forms;
using MimeDetective;

namespace MimeDetectiveTest
{
    public partial class Form1 : Form
    {
        private OpenFileDialog openFile;
        private ContentInspectorBuilder inspector;
        public Form1()
        {
            InitializeComponent();
            openFile = new OpenFileDialog();
            inspector = new ContentInspectorBuilder()
            {
                Definitions = new MimeDetective.Definitions.ExhaustiveBuilder()
                {
                    UsageType = MimeDetective.Definitions.Licensing.UsageType.PersonalNonCommercial
                }.Build()
            };
        }

        private String findFileType(String path)
        {
            var content = ContentReader.Default.ReadFromFile(path);
            var results = ContentInspectorExtensions.Inspect(inspector, content);
            return results.ByFileExtension().ToString();
        }

        private void openFileButton_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            if (openFile.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
            {
                try
                {
                    var filePath = openFile.FileName;
                    var fileExtension = Path.GetExtension(filePath);
                    var newFileExtension = findFileType(filePath);
                    filePathLabel.Text = filePath;
                    extensionLabel.Visible = true;
                    extensionLabel.Text = "File Identified - " + newFileExtension;
                }
                catch (SecurityException ex)
                {
                    MessageBox.Show($"Security error.\n\nError message: {ex.Message}\n\n" +
                    $"Details:\n\n{ex.StackTrace}");
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

The closest I've gotten to it working how I wanted is using this [Github for another Mime-Detective](https://github.com/Muraad/Mime-Detective) but if I send specific file formats (.xml or .flac as examples), the entire thing crashes or it outputs nothing (.htm as an example). Code is similar to the top one, just remove the inspector from the starting bit of code and change the findFileType method to this:

```
private String findFileType(String path)
    {
        Stream fileDataStream = File.Open(path, FileMode.Open);
        FileType fileType = fileDataStream.GetFileType();
        return fileType.Extension;
    }
```

Comment: Hiya, this cannot be done uniformely.
Depending on what specific types you want to identify, such could be detectable according to headers and such, but really all possible is to try to convert them to specific things and seeing it fail will confirm what it is not, which is by nature not deterministic by any chance

Comment: Maybe [this](https://superuser.com/questions/274734/how-can-i-determine-file-type-without-an-extension-on-windows) can help you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you just missed one `Build()`.

If you compare the example code on github:

```
var Inspector = new ContentInspectorBuilder() {
    Definitions = new Definitions.ExhaustiveBuilder() {
        UsageType = Definitions.Licensing.UsageType.PersonalNonCommercial
    }.Build()
}.Build(); // <=====
```

to your code:

```
inspector = new ContentInspectorBuilder()
{
    Definitions = new MimeDetective.Definitions.ExhaustiveBuilder()
    {
        UsageType = MimeDetective.Definitions.Licensing.UsageType.PersonalNonCommercial
    }.Build()
}; // <=====
```

you'll find that they are operating on the result that the builder builds (which is a `ContentInspector`, not a `ContentInspectorBuilder`), not on the builder itself. Which also explains the missing method.

And actually, I am wondering how this line

```
var results = ContentInspectorExtensions.Inspect(inspector, content);
```

didn't throw. Or did it? I couldn't find a matching extension on the Builder type. So, I would have expected a related error.

Comment: Ah that bottom line. Forgot to replace it to how the example code shows it. That is what VS suggests changing it to to try and fix the lack of an inspect method.

Comment: Right. Then, you can also change that to `inspector.Inspect(content)` - which is the usage you would expect froman extension method.

Comment: Well that would have been a nice fix if it wasnt for the fact that now the entire block of code comes up with an error saying it can't convert ContentInspector to ContentInspectorBuilder for some reason.

Comment: Because it _isn't_ a ContentInspectorBuilder. The result of the Builder's `Build`method is a `ContentInspector`: `public ContentInspector Build() {`

Comment: Okay I think I get it now. Changed it to a var fixed it :)